# VBA - How to combine/compile 2 Worksheet_Change events

Tags: excel, vba

New to VBA and coding and like many, I have trawled the web to find code that does what I'm trying to do and attempted to make it fit my goal.

I am trying to achieve 2 things; First, to be able to pick multiple items from a dropdown list in 2 specific columns. Secondly to call a datestamp (and user) whenever information on that row is updated.

I have found and modified code for both of these tasks and can get both tasks to run independently but don't know how to combine them to get both functions together.

I have seen a suggestion for calling 2 events:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Call ChangeEvent1(Target)
    Call ChangeEvent2(Target)
End Sub
```

but I'm not sure how to utilize this or if its better to rewrite the 2 events into one...

TASK 1, Datestamp code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim cell As Range
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("Owner, State, Percentage, Permits, Civil, Vegetation, Arch, Outages, Material,  Comment")) Is Nothing Then
        For Each cell In Intersect(Target, Me.Range("Owner, State, Percentage, Permits, Civil, Vegetation, Arch, Outages, Material, Comment"))
            If cell.Value <> "" Then
                Me.Cells(cell.Row, "R").Value = Now()
                Me.Cells(cell.Row, "S").Value = Application.UserName
                
            Else
                Me.Cells(cell.Row, "R").ClearContents
                Me.Cells(cell.Row, "S").ClearContents
                
            End If
        Next cell
    End If
End Sub
```

TASK 2, Dropdown Multiselection Code for columns 7 and 10:

- I got this from the Ablebits guide [here](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/create-multi-select-dropdown-excel/#multi-selection-dropdown-item-removal-code)

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Destination As Range)
Dim rngDropdown As Range
Dim oldValue As String
Dim newValue As String
Dim DelimiterType As String
DelimiterType = " | "
Dim DelimiterCount As Integer
Dim TargetType As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim arr() As String
 
If Destination.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
On Error Resume Next
 
Set rngDropdown = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation)
On Error GoTo exitError
 
If rngDropdown Is Nothing Then GoTo exitError
If Destination.Column <> 7 And Destination.Column <> 10 Then GoTo exitError
 
TargetType = 0
    TargetType = Destination.Validation.Type
    If TargetType = 3 Then  ' is validation type is "list"
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        newValue = Destination.Value
        Application.Undo
        oldValue = Destination.Value
        Destination.Value = newValue
        If oldValue <> "" Then
            If newValue <> "" Then
                If oldValue = newValue Or oldValue = newValue & Replace(DelimiterType, " ", "") Or oldValue = newValue & DelimiterType Then ' leave the value if there is only one in the list
                    oldValue = Replace(oldValue, DelimiterType, "")
                    oldValue = Replace(oldValue, Replace(DelimiterType, " ", ""), "")
                    Destination.Value = oldValue
                ElseIf InStr(1, oldValue, DelimiterType & newValue) Or InStr(1, oldValue, " " & newValue & DelimiterType) Then
                    arr = Split(oldValue, DelimiterType)
                If Not IsError(Application.Match(newValue, arr, 0)) = 0 Then
                    Destination.Value = oldValue & DelimiterType & newValue
                        Else:
                    Destination.Value = ""
                    For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
                    If arr(i) <> newValue Then
                        Destination.Value = Destination.Value & arr(i) & DelimiterType
                    End If
                    Next i
                Destination.Value = Left(Destination.Value, Len(Destination.Value) - Len(DelimiterType))
                End If
                ElseIf InStr(1, oldValue, newValue & Replace(DelimiterType, " ", "")) Then
                    oldValue = Replace(oldValue, newValue, "")
                    Destination.Value = oldValue
                Else
                    Destination.Value = oldValue & DelimiterType & newValue
                End If
                Destination.Value = Replace(Destination.Value, Replace(DelimiterType, " ", "") & Replace(DelimiterType, " ", ""), Replace(DelimiterType, " ", "")) ' remove extra commas and spaces
                Destination.Value = Replace(Destination.Value, DelimiterType & Replace(DelimiterType, " ", ""), Replace(DelimiterType, " ", ""))
                If Destination.Value <> "" Then
                    If Right(Destination.Value, 2) = DelimiterType Then  ' remove delimiter at the end
                        Destination.Value = Left(Destination.Value, Len(Destination.Value) - 2)
                    End If
                End If
                If InStr(1, Destination.Value, DelimiterType) = 1 Then ' remove delimiter as first characters
                    Destination.Value = Replace(Destination.Value, DelimiterType, "", 1, 1)
                End If
                If InStr(1, Destination.Value, Replace(DelimiterType, " ", "")) = 1 Then
                    Destination.Value = Replace(Destination.Value, Replace(DelimiterType, " ", ""), "", 1, 1)
                End If
                DelimiterCount = 0
                For i = 1 To Len(Destination.Value)
                    If InStr(i, Destination.Value, Replace(DelimiterType, " ", "")) Then
                        DelimiterCount = DelimiterCount + 1
                    End If
                Next i
                If DelimiterCount = 1 Then ' remove delimiter if last character
                    Destination.Value = Replace(Destination.Value, DelimiterType, "")
                    Destination.Value = Replace(Destination.Value, Replace(DelimiterType, " ", ""), "")
                End If
            End If
        End If
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End If
 
exitError:
  Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: too little context for me. you may consider adding some examples (screenshots) of what you're trying to achieve

Comment: *I have seen a suggestion for calling 2 events:*, you're calling it there from Selection_Change however, not the Change event you're using in the subs you've shown. If you'd change that, it'd work. If you want to shove them into one, then you'd need to know if target can intersect with both ,if not, there's no real point in combining them.